# Mysql - PhpMyAdmin erro ao executar trigger

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Olá, quando tento executar a seguinte trigger, obtenho este erro:

> #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a linha 11

**Segue a trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER atualizacao
after update ON cliente
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE VERX VARCHAR(10);
    SET VERX=(SELECT DESCRICAO FROM versao WHERE id=NEW.id_versao);
    if(OLD.id_versao<NEW.id_versao)then
    begin
        INSERT INTO tarefa (id_cliente,id_servico,dt_cadastro,dt_inicio,dt_final,hora_inicio,hora_final,situacao,descricao,solucao,prioridade,id_projeto,tipo) VALUES(NEW.id_cliente,10,now(),now(),now(),now(),now(),2,'Atualização',CONCAT('Sistema atualizado para versão ',VERX),1,1,0);
    end;
END$$
```

Gostaria de saber o que poderia ser...

Comment: Qual a linha 11? Seria a linha "END$$"?

Comment: Seu select não está faltando **JOIN** ? de onde vem o campo WHERE id=NEW.id_versao ?

Comment: @EdvaldoLucena o `NEW.id_versao` é o último id alterado, não precisa de join

Comment: @RicardoPontual isso mesmo, a linha 11 é a última

Comment: a última linha não seria `END;$$`?

Comment: @RicardoPontual já tentei, acontece a mesma coisa..

Comment: Acredito que ali ao invés de `end;` seja `end if;` já que você não fechou o `IF`

Comment: Na real acredito que ali antes do `INSERT` nem é necessário abrir um novo `begin`

Comment: @EvaldoRc sua trigger faz o quê? Você não detalhou o que ela faz.

Comment: Aham, fiz as alterações (removendo o begin e colocando end if) e funcionou, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que está ocasionando o erro de fato é a ausência do `DELIMITER$$` no início do código mas há também alguns outros erros na `TRIGGER` descrita.

Primeiro que você acabou não fechando o `IF` e também não há necessidade de abrir um segundo `BEGIN` antes do `INSERT`. Tente dessa forma:

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE TRIGGER atualizacao
after update ON cliente
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE VERX VARCHAR(10);
    SET VERX=(SELECT DESCRICAO FROM versao WHERE id=NEW.id_versao);
    if(OLD.id_versao<NEW.id_versao)then
        INSERT INTO tarefa (id_cliente,id_servico,dt_cadastro,dt_inicio,dt_final,hora_inicio,hora_final,situacao,descricao,solucao,prioridade,id_projeto,tipo) VALUES(NEW.id_cliente,10,now(),now(),now(),now(),now(),2,'Atualização',CONCAT('Sistema atualizado para versão ',VERX),1,1,0);
    end if;
END$$
```

Comment: muito obrigado, realmente funcionou agora!!